# Register a user with anonymous User ID

Tags: php, sql

I create an application that will show users registered in the system on a map. But I need to adhere to some kind of security:

1. I want to store the user information (name, address etc)
2. I create a UUID for each user
3. This UUID is the only reference being
   displayed on the map, so the user of the map cannot see the clear
   names
4. the UUID is connected with a user directly and only with
   this user.

I dont'see at the moment how to solve the issue, that a user registers in my database and gets a UUID assigned, but it should not be traceable at the end, which UUID is connected with which user. I hope my problem came across.

In terms of privacy issues, I should not be able to see clear names in a database for each user so data privacy is ensured and only UUIDs are a reference. How can I solve this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to solve? Why shouldn't someone with full access to the database be able to match the user and UUID?

Comment: The basic idea was, that the user can be anonymous and I only see this UUID when he registers.

Comment: does anyone else has access to the database? (directly not via the application)

Comment: nope. But in terms of privacy regulations I thought this would be safe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a 100% sure of why and what you'd want to achieve but it seems like you have 2 options:

- Encryption - if you're afraid someone will get sensitive data from your database, consider encryption. When it comes to UUID you are always going to be needing some sort of way to identify a user so the only way to protect your data is encryption.
- If you're afraid someone else from your team (who has direct access to the database) may take advantage of the sensitive information (like get the address of a user) you could create a separate pivot table which correlates between the user data and the uuid i.e `user_uuid` and this table will contain `user_id`,`user_uuid` (the first one is numeric index, the second one is the uuid). Then you could create access control rules on the database itself and only you will be able to access the main `user` table, everyone else won't.

Hope this helps.

Comment: perfect! the second approach sounds good! Yes.. it is about the possibility, that sensitive data could be accessed if stored in one database. My idea was to setup two different databases hosted on two different servers with two different locations).

Comment: One more question came up.... Why is a pivot table necessary as the UUIDs are unique and therefore only one user will have one UUID. So it isn't a many to many case, is it?

Comment: @sesc360 It is not needed. It is only there since you don't want other people to have access to the main user table, so it only serves as a translation table.

Comment: ah now I get it... cool! Already installed and runs smoothly :) Thank you!